# ignore too much taken space in new line in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i have a list text and it takes new line and to much take space in that new line, how to ignore that in flutter to make text fit and no space in new line ??

here is my code for that list :

```
         Container(
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Flexible(
                          flex: 1,
                          fit: FlexFit.loose,
                          child: Text("$index. ", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white) ),
                        ),
                        Flexible(
                          flex:2,
                          fit: FlexFit.tight,
                          child: Text(step, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  );
```

[image: list text screenshot]

Comment: you can make text smaller using `Text("Sample one", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 10)),`

Comment: sorry , i was asking how to make no space too much on new line what i want

Comment: do you want to see less space between lines?

Answer (score 0):

Simply set height for `Container` like this:

```
  Container(
                height: 20,
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Flexible(
                      flex: 1,
                      fit: FlexFit.loose,
                      child: Text("$index. ", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white) ),
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      flex:2,
                      fit: FlexFit.tight,
                      child: Text(step, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              );
```

Comment: it makes the another lines gone